# How to write a nested loop

Tags: matlab, loops, nested, sum

How can I run a loop in blocks, that is if i have an idx=[ 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 ]' and I want sum the elements of A [ 0 2 2 2 1 2 4 5 2 6]' to produce B=[4 3 13 6]. That is B=[0+2+2 2+1 2+4+5+2 6]

Comment: please elaborate the question

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, i do not see how it is?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear to me, but I can venture a guess.

I think you are trying to:

for each unique value in `idx`, sum the the values in A where the indices match the given unique value in `idx`.

If so,

`value = accumarray(idx, A)`

`idx` must be a column vector, so if it is not, pass `idx'`.